# Ngbootstrap error trying to use typeahead with angular 10

Tags: angular, observable, ng-bootstrap

I'm facing a problem with my code. I want to implement typeahead of ngbootstrap but i got this error on the browse.

```
ERROR TypeError: Object(...)(...) is not a function
 at Observable.pipe (Observable.js:85)
 at NgbTypeahead.ngOnInit (ng-bootstrap.js:11786)
 at callHook (core.js:3038)   ..................
```

I'm working on angular 10 and i'm using ngbootstrap 8.0.2 version

This is the peace of code in my component

```
 this.airportService.getAirportsIfExist(airportName)
 .subscribe(result => {
    this.airportList = result;
      if(this.airportList.length==0){
        this.airportListSize = false;
      }
      else{
        this.airportListSize = true;
        this.searchVille = (text$: Observable<any>) =>
          text$.pipe(
            debounceTime(200),
            distinctUntilChanged(),
            map(term => term.length < 1 ? []
              : this.airportList.filter(v => v['name'].toLowerCase().startsWith(term.toLocaleLowerCase())).splice(0, 10))
          )
              }
});
```

And in the html file i got this

```
    <input formControlName="villeDep" id="departureTown"  type="text" name="town" autocomplete="off" required [ngbTypeahead]="searchVille"/>
```

I don't now what happen and the docs doesn't give enougth information about.

Can somebody help me pleeeeeaaaaaassssssseeeeee???

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you need defined `searchVille` **always** (not under a subscribe) So, when declare the variable check also is !this.airportList (see the comment)

```
//when you declare the variable
searchVille = (text$: Observable<any>) =>
      text$.pipe(
            debounceTime(200),
            distinctUntilChanged(),
            //see the condition now is "term.length<1 || !this.airportList"
            map(term => term.length<1 || !this.airportList ? []
              : this.airportList.filter(v => v['name'].toLowerCase().startsWith(term.toLocaleLowerCase())).splice(0, 10))
          )
```

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't help me, i finally found a way buy putting the block code of "searchville" variable outside the "this.airportService.getAirportsIfExist(airportName)" function and it works.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion   map(term => term.length<1 || !this.airportList ? []
              : .....